# Google drive API method to get storage capacity gives error

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

REf url:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

When I am using the about methods, getting below error:

> An error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global",
>   "reason": "required", "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required
>   for this method.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fields" }
>   ], "code": 400, "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for
>   this method." } }

This is my code:

```
function printAbout() {
    try {
        $about = $this->service->about->get(array('fields' => 'name'));
        print "Current user name: " . $about->getName();
        print "Root folder ID: " . $about->getRootFolderId();
        print "Total quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesTotal();
        print "Used quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesUsed();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear. How did you try to use the method?  Did you include the "fields" parameter?

Comment: i tried with fields and without but no use

Comment: @Timst, this is my code  function printAbout() {
   try {
    
  $about = $this->service->about->get(array('fields' => 'name'));

  print "Current user name: " . $about->getName();
  print "Root folder ID: " . $about->getRootFolderId();
  print "Total quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesTotal();
  print "Used quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesUsed();
   } catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
 }</code>

Comment: Do you get the same result when *trying out the API* in the page?

Comment: yes i am getting error

Comment: An error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fields" } ], "code": 400, "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for this method." } }

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of the *Try out this API* so we can see details?

Comment: i cant able to share it.

Comment: When i am trying to call the method getting error "An error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fields" } ], "code": 400, "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for this method." } }" in page. other than this nothing is there in screen

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't figured this out yet I've got your answer.

You are linking to the V2 version of the documentation but you are using V3 in your code. In V2, you do not need to specify the fields param and thus it should run completely fine through the API tester. It is likely that you linked the V2 documentation in your post but are using the V3 documentation yourself to do the testing.

The /drive/about/get API changed from V2 to V3. Specifically the layout of the returned information is not different. So when you specify 'name' as a field, it doesn't exist and you continue to get that (fairly unhelpful) error.

**To fix your problem**

Specify 'user' in the 'fields' param rather than 'name' and it will return the data that you want in result.user.displayName.

**Documentation**

[V2 About/Get Result Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource)

[V3 About/Get Result Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about#resource)

I hope that the explanation is helpful and that you can properly get your data!

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js, this works:

```
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: authClient }); 
drive.about.get({
   auth: authClient,
   fields: ["storageQuota"]
}, function (err, resp) {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   console.log(resp)
});
```